# Is it possible in Polars to "reset" cumsum() at a certain condition?

Tags: python-polars

I need to cumsum the column b until a becomes True. After that cumsum shall start from this row and so on.

```py
df = pl.from_repr("""
┌───────┬─────┐
│ a     ┆ b   │
│ ---   ┆ --- │
│ bool  ┆ i64 │
╞═══════╪═════╡
│ false ┆ 1   │
│ false ┆ 2   │
│ true  ┆ 3   │
│ false ┆ 4   │
└───────┴─────┘
""")
```

Expected Output:

```py
┌───────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a     ┆ b   ┆ sum │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ bool  ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ false ┆ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ false ┆ 2   ┆ 3   │
│ true  ┆ 3   ┆ 3   │
│ false ┆ 4   ┆ 7   │
└───────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Can I do it on Polars without looping each row?

Comment: What is the expected output? `[1, 3, 3, 7]`? `[1, 3, 6, 4]`?

Comment: [1, 3, 3, 7] in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`.cum_sum()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.cum_sum.html#polars.Expr.cum_sum) itself can be used as the "group id".

```py
df.with_columns(
   group = pl.col("a").cum_sum()
)
```

```py
shape: (4, 3)
┌───────┬─────┬───────┐
│ a     ┆ b   ┆ group │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ ---   │
│ bool  ┆ i64 ┆ u32   │
╞═══════╪═════╪═══════╡
│ false ┆ 1   ┆ 0     │
│ false ┆ 2   ┆ 0     │
│ true  ┆ 3   ┆ 1     │
│ false ┆ 4   ┆ 1     │
└───────┴─────┴───────┘
```

Which can be used with [`.over()`](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/expressions/window/)

```py
df.with_columns(
   sum = pl.col("b").cum_sum().over(pl.col("a").cum_sum())
)
```

```py
shape: (4, 3)
┌───────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a     ┆ b   ┆ sum │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ bool  ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ false ┆ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ false ┆ 2   ┆ 3   │
│ true  ┆ 3   ┆ 3   │
│ false ┆ 4   ┆ 7   │
└───────┴─────┴─────┘
```