polars cumsum on column if value changes
I'm stuck with a cum_sum problem where I only want tot cumulatively sum unique values over a column.
Here's an example of what I want to achieve:
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ d   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   │
│ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 3   │
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 4   │
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 4   │
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 5   │
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 5   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘

a and b are my input columns where a is the group and b is the unique id within he group. I want to generate d which is a unique id across all groups. I'm not able to figure out a way to do this.
Here's what I've managed - I can get the max per group by using over but then I don't know how to do the cumsum to get the unique ids.
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2], 
                   'b': [1,2,3,1,1,2,2,2]})

df.with_columns(c = pl.max('b').over('a')).with_columns(pl.cum_sum("c").over("c").alias("d"))

Out[60]: 
shape: (8, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ d   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 3   │
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 6   │
│ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 3   ┆ 9   │
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 12  │
│ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   │
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 4   │
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 6   │
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 8   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘


I'm sure this must be pretty simple but I can't figure this out - It seems like I need a cumsum the unique values of c and then add to b to get the unique id but maybe I need some sort of conditional sum of c only if it's values changes?
It seems like I should be doing something similar to this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/74985568/1506763) but I'm stuck.

You might be looking for pl.Expr.rank with method="dense".
df.with_columns(
    pl.struct("a", "b").rank("dense").alias("id")
)

shape: (8, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ id  │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ u32 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 2   │
│ 1   ┆ 3   ┆ 3   │
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 4   │
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 5   │
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 5   │
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 5   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘

